# Unable to resolve "@babel/runtime/regenerator" from

Tags: react-native, babeljs

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this issue? I had try to run `yarn add babel-runtime` which I got the solution from other question. But the problem didn't go away.
At first I thought is the expo version problem , so I updated my expo version. This error is still there.